# React Fetch API in Laravel application

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

I've seen this not-so-perfect solution where we're supposed to place a universal view route and then route everything from react-router like so:

```
Route::view('/{any}', 'layouts.app')->where('any', '.*');
```

or

```
Route::view('/{any?}', 'layouts.app');
```

But the big issue here is when I'm fetching data to react from within my laravel application, for example: `/posts`, react-router will try to resolve `/posts`, but laravel will match it with `/{any?}`, and **the fetch call will respond with a view**.

Is there a way to make `apiResource` calls like described, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your API routes with the 'api' prefix `'api/posts'` (for example).
Then let your react router do the routing for the application using one universal route:

```
Route::view('/{any?}', 'layouts.app');
```

This route comes **after** your API routes so that your API routes don't get matched with `{'/any?'}` parameter. (Very important!)

Then, you can have something like this in your react app:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts/>} />
</Routes>
```